# Plot group bar chart plotly python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to make a grouped bar chart in plotly python. But I have not been able to get it to work. It has drawn me the general groups (API1, API2, API3) but it draws me the accumulated bars and I want differentiated bars for each of the S1, S2 and S3

|  | API1 | API2 | API3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | 41 | 56 | 48 |
| s2 | 40 | 50 | 45 |
| s3 | 15 | 24 | 8 |

This is the output I have, but I can't get individual bars to be created for each of the groups.

[image]

Comment: post your dataframe as a dict please, so we can recreate your issue.

Comment: Try the following code. `import plotly.express as px;df = df.T;px.bar(df, x=df.index, y=['s1','s2','s3'], barmode='stack')`

Answer (score 2):

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'index': 'group'}, inplace=True)
df
##
  group  API1  API2  API3
0    s1    41    56    48
1    s2    40    50    45
2    s3    15    24     8
```

```
df_plot = df.melt(value_vars=df.columns, id_vars='group')
df_plot
###
  group variable  value
0    s1     API1     41
1    s2     API1     40
2    s3     API1     15
3    s1     API2     56
4    s2     API2     50
5    s3     API2     24
6    s1     API3     48
7    s2     API3     45
8    s3     API3      8
```

Plot

```
fig = px.histogram(df_plot, x='variable', y='value', color='index', barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

[image]

```
fig2 = px.histogram(df_plot, x='variable', y='value', color='index')
fig2.show()
```

[image]