# How to make bar plot with legend based on another column value dash plotly

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly-dash

Dataframe has 3 columns. First is values for x axis, second is value for y axis, third is groupping.

for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'for_x':['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6'], 'for_y':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'for_color': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]}, ignore_index=True)
```

I need to make bar chart with legend, based on third columns values.

If i use "color" parametr of px.bar it expects several values for each "x" value and moves each bar from center and also make it narrow.

Couldnt find any solutions in docs, so please help)

Comment: Update. Found in my code "barmode = group". That made everything move.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot group bar chart plotly python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73138287/plot-group-bar-chart-plotly-python)

Comment: Nope, thats exactly the oposite of what i was looking for. But i managed to figure it out myself, that just was my misread of code example i found.

Comment: It literally has `barmode='group'` in the answer for the first plot but ok....